# Shortcuts in Android app

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat

Can shortcuts to specific actions in your app be defined, if the app targets API level less than Android 7.1 (API level 25).

> According to [Developer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html), If your app targets Android 7.1 (API
>   level 25) or higher, you can define shortcuts to specific actions in
>   your app.

Answer (score 1):

Static shortcuts should not take `targetSdkVersion` into account, as they may be supported on older devices, where the user has installed a home screen implementation that happens to look for static shortcut metadata.

Dynamic shortcuts require a `compileSdkVersion` of 25 or higher. AFAIK, `targetSdkVersion` does not affect this either.